# Изменение цвета в ritchTextBox

Tags: c#

Попытался сделать изменение цвета у последней строки, но увы если добавить третью строку, третья и все последующие приобретают цвет, как у третей строки. Что не так?

```
public void rich_text_set(Color color_text, string text)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text +=  text + Environment.NewLine;
            if (richTextBox1.Lines.Length > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(0, richTextBox1.Lines[0].Length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color_text;
            }
            if (richTextBox1.Lines.Length > 1)
            {
                var leng_rich = richTextBox1.Lines.Length-1;
                richTextBox1.Select(leng_rich, richTextBox1.Lines[leng_rich].Length);
                 richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color_text;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
        private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox.Text.Length == 0)
                return;

            // Если появилась новая строка, то сбрасываем цвет на стандартный
            if (richTextBox.Text[richTextBox.Text.Length - 1] == '\n')
            {
                // Сбрасываем цвет у всего текста
                richTextBox.SelectAll();
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = richTextBox.ForeColor;
                // Убираем выделение
                richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                // Ставим курсор после последнего символа
                richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
            }
            // Если текст дописывалься в конец
            if (richTextBox.SelectionStart == richTextBox.Text.Length)
            {
                // Теперь последней строке устанавливаем наш цвет (будет красный)
                string prevLine = richTextBox.Lines[richTextBox.Lines.Length - 1];
                richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(prevLine);
                richTextBox.SelectionLength = prevLine.Length;
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                // Убираем выделение
                richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
                // Ставим курсор после последнего символа
                richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
            }
        }
```

---

```
        void AddText(string text, Color color)
        {
            //// Добавляем текст
            richTextBox.AppendText(text + "\n");
            // Устанавливаем цвет
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(text);
            richTextBox.SelectionLength = text.Length;
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
            // Убираем выделение
            richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            // Ставим курсор после последнего символа
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
        }
```

Comment: А можно как то без взаимодействия с курсором?
Вообще мне нужно что бы цвет последней строки менялся на указанный мной. 
И при этом цвет других строк оставался тем же.

Comment: Я не так Вас понял значит. Обновил ответ

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static void HighlightLastRow(this RichTextBox rtb, Color color)
{
   string line = rtb.Lines[rtb.Lines.Count() - 1];
   rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.Text.LastIndexOf(line);
   rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.Text.Length - 1;
   rtb.SelectionColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Нет, увы. Такая же проблема, как и выше.